Can natural decreasing temperatures in the world create energy to power it?
When the compound water experiences a drop in ambient temperature it freezes and becomes a solid.
When water freezes it expands.
Can you harness the energy in this expansion to produce energy such as electricity generated by a motor? The movement of the expansion could turn a alternator or generator and produce a current.
How does conservation of energy in a closed system resolve this local paradox. Where is the energy coming from in the movement and expansion of water?

These questions belong on engineering SE or history of science SE (how can or how did people use the mechanical work of freezing?) and on physics SE (where does the energy come from to do mechanical work by the expansion of freezing water?). Separate them before posting, or they'll likely be closed as needing focus. Search those stacks briefly first, also; the questions have likely been asked and answered already.

However, comprehending the huge amount of energy involved in the vaporization / condensation and thawing / freezing transitions is quite eye opening to an understanding of the weather and the world in general! Water is a stunningly non-obvious substance, and without it, basically nothing would happen on this planet.

@gs Is free energy not just in the realm of physics but also in the realm of philosophy? contemporary and ancient thought?

@8Mad0Manc8 it's not in the realm of philosophy SE.

@gs Is that an assertion?

I don't see a paradox here. As water freezes, the ambient medium warms up. There is a flow of energy from water to ambience. If you harness, and channel away some of this flow, it only means that the ambience wouldn't warm up as much.

@user58697 If the background temperature is warming up how does that background temperature continue to cool down. With some pondering maybe its something to do with latent heat in the transition of state?

The temperature stops dropping when snow starts to fall in most cases, because the snow releases heat to the atmosphere as it forms. Similarly, the temperature can't fall past the dew point at night because water condenses and releases heat. These flows power all weather phenomena on earth. This is the very thing you asked about. We harness this energy from wind.

@ScottRowe We harness energy from the sun's fusion and gravity. gas oil and coal are all organic and presumably geothermal is a result of the sun and our planets origin. A net energy loss in the sun's energy would result in an overall loss in net temperature. However, since most of the planets surface is water, we could benefit from the net cooling. How practical this is is questionable.

Gas, oil and coal are "fossil fuels", ancient plant material crushed by overlying sediments. The energy is stored photosynthesis. Without life, that energy would have radiated away as heat the day after it fell. Radioactive material in the earth is probably from the time it formed.

Energy from nuclear fission. If we could replicate fussion that is controllable amd does not have the associated explosive characteristics then that would be  solution to the energy crisis. I don't think my question is the answer to the energy crisis its too unpractical howver its a form of free energy like fussion, amd wind, geothermal, hydroelectric and tidal gravity.

In principle, you could use the expansion of water as it freezes to do mechanical work. But if you needed to expend energy to freeze the water, there would be no net gain. If you relied instead on winter coming round to freeze the water, there wouldn't be a lot of ice in a position where it would be convenient to harness it. Pack ice at sea floats and would be infeasible to harness. You could fill some containers with water and wait for them to freeze, but it would be very inefficient.

@Bumble I had thought of the container if you used the sides base and bottom of the container with material. Then pour water in to the container put a heavy lid on the container and have the lid attached to a counter weight as the the water freezes in winter the lid rise and when the water thaws the lid lifts the counter weight it is plausible to use this system during the changes in season from autumm to winter as the water freezes and winter to spring as the water thaws let the external ambient temperature do the work

There is a lot of confusion here, both in the comments and the answer -- if you want good answers to a thermodynamics question (which is what this), you need to ask physicists or maybe engineers, not philosophers. The short answer is that the energy comes from the internal energy of the water. Ice has lower internal energy than liquid water. Normally, when you freeze water, you extract that energy in the form of heat, but in this case you're extracting part of it as work instead. You could build a heat engine this way, but it wouldn't be a very good one.

Super duper question. I recall reading how water that seeps into rocks through natural pores & cracks can break them when the temperature drops to/below freezing. My answer would be that the energy to do the work of breaking the rocks comes from the energy that is released when water becomes ice. No paradox there I suppose.

Yeah maybe atomic energy provides the energy for the work done because the net input from background energyt the sun reduces as we orbit it..The fact is it happens however I'm bamboozled.

How can it be a “super duper question” here on philosophy SE? What does it have to do with philosophy at all? It’s physics and technology.

@PaulTanenbaum Freedom an the concept freedom is a philosophical question as is the philosophy of science. This is a scientific question that's interest is on a practical level as well as a phillosopgical question. Can you get something for nothing?

@PaulTanenbaum, sorry if that was an inappropriate remark. Philosophers tend the roots I suppose. Once in a while we may taste of a fruit? :)
